# if statement in angularjs is not working

Tags: angularjs

i have a login page which evaluates username and password using angularjs
but it seems that my conditional statement in the controller returns false even if i put a true value

here's my html file

```
<div class="row">
<form action="/">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="username" required>                     
    <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="password" required>                     
    <br>
    <button type="button" style="width: 40%;"  ng-click="submit()"> Log In </button>

</form>     
</div>
```

and my controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.controller('ctrl',
 function($scope, $location) { 

    $scope.submit = function() {
        var username = $scope.username;
        var password = $scope.password;

        if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
            console.debug('success');
        } else {
            console.debug('fail');
        }
    }


});
```

every time i input 'admin' in username and password i always get 'fail' in my console which means the submit function returns false . .

Comment: `<input type="Password" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="password"` is that right? should the id not be `password`?

Comment: opps type thats should be id="password" but i think thats not causing the problem since im not using id atm if im not wrong

Comment: can you make a plunkr illustrating your issues

Answer (score 1):

1) Per the HTML spec you need to cannot have the same id on 2 different elements
[html 4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)

2)You should explicitly declare the objects you want your control to have injected like below. That way when you minifiy your code, the Dependency injection will continue to work

```
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope','$location'
 function($scope, $location) { }]);
```

3) TO answer your question why isnt this working. My [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gHVdOBXg3bavID2Sw57q?p=preview) works. I removed the routing, because it wasnt needed. Make sure you are typing in 'admin' no spaces/caps

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <form action="/">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="username" required>                     
            <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="password" required>                     
            <br>
            <button type="button" style="width: 40%;"  ng-click="submit()"> Log In </button>

        </form>     
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',["ngRoute"]);

        app.controller('ctrl',
                       function($scope, $location) { 

            $scope.submit = function() {
                var username = $scope.username;
                var password = $scope.password;

                if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
                    console.debug('success');
                } else {
                    console.debug('fail');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```